# User delete policy? Re: Baelnorn [aka Damnit-just delete me already]

Tags: support

RE: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/660/damnit-just-delete-me-already

What's the story? Can't someone delete their account?

Answer (score 2):

To delete your account, you have to edit your user info to "delete me please" and send in an e-mail. There's no automatic system for it.

No idea why Baelnorn wants to delete his account. He has high reputation and hasn't posted on the site since April.

Answer (score 2):

First I've heard of it, whatever emails he's sending must be going to the core SE team or something.  I have hit the 'delete' button on his account.  I'm unclear how it differs from the core team doing a "bigger" delete but don't really care. Should be gone.

For future reference, if you are upset to the point where you want to delete your account, just bring it to mod attention and we'll do it for ya.

Comment: We use the same tools you do for deletion.